# Error in init script on a fi line

Tags: bash, if-statement, debian

i use a init scipt to start my ndo2db for nagios and get an error.

This is the part of the script who creates the issue.

```
# Checking for help input
if [[ "${INPUT}" ~= ".*help$" ]]; then
HELP;
fi
```

This is the errormessage:

```
/etc/init.d/ndodaemon: 63: [[: not found
```

The complete script can be found here:
[ndodaemonscript](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70024219/ndodaemon.txt)

I'm don't know what to do now. :-(

I've tried several things. (I'm a script rookie)

- only one pair of []
- replaced the "" with nothing and ''
- checked out where my bash is --> /bin/sh
- removed all []

My System:

- Latest Debian 6.0.7
- Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 00:26:11 UTC 2013 x86_64

Greetings :-)

P.S.: Sorry for my bad englisch I'm a german dude. ;)

Comment: `sh` doesn't support `bash` features.

Comment: Ok. And what should i do to get this working?
Can someone help me to convert it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[` is a bashism. Change the shebang line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

In some Linux distributions, `/bin/sh` calls bash and everything works. In some others, like Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` calls `/bin/dash` which does not implement `[[`.

Comment: You saved my day. Sometimes it can be so easy. Thanks for the tip now everything works. :-)

Comment: Sorry can't Vote. Vote Up requires 15 reputation :-(